# SSIS package connection string error - "8.0;HDR=YES"

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I'm trying to schedule an Export to Excel from SQL Server and I've used the Export Wizard from SSMS and selected the option to Create SSIS package, right before finishing the export.

I've created this package and then continued with creating a Job, added a Step and selected the package which I previously created, to run with this job.

But when running the job, I get an error and when reviewing the Job History, the error says that there is an error at "8.0;HDR=YES".

When reviewing the connection string for this, I can see that the error is generated at Extended Properties.

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\DCTIS\DataFeed\DataFeedTest.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES";`

I've tried multiple solutions from online, from adding extra double quotes before and after the Extended Properties, removing double quotes before `EXCEL` and after `YES`, adding slashes `\` before and after Excel (I'm assuming in order to Escape the double quote characters), but nothing has worked.

So, I'd rather try and understand why this error occurs, because I would feel that it could bring me closer to a solution rather than just making small "hacks" to the ConnectionString.

Any suggestions/explanations are very much appreciated!

Comment: what credential is the SSIS package running under and does it have permission to the UNC path? Is is a windows domain account?

Comment: @Donal I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand what credential you are referring to. The only credentials I've used when creating the SSIS package were the ones for accessing SQL Server (I could choose between `Use Windows Authentication` and `Use SQL Server Authentication`.

Comment: The SSIS package has to run under a particular security context - under a credential. For example, the SQL Server Agent service account. If that account does not have privileges to access the share containing the Excel file - then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link https://connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/, check that there's one space between ";" and "HDR", or try changing the provider for "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" instead of "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

Comment: The space after the semicolon is not required. I would be surprised  if it actually worked but am too lazy/hate working with excel to test.